# Rails Transaction update multiple database columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, transactions

Hello I need to create a rake task that runs thru the database and updated the 91,000 records that I have on the db. The task need to update 4 params and make them upcase, however, some of those params may be nil or and empty string, im trying to iterate thru the params array and update them if they have a value different to nil or ''. any idea on how to make it work?
thanks

```
task :data_uppercase => [ :environment ] do
  file = File.open("caVoters.txt", "w")
  cali_voter = CaVoter.where(tag: "ventura-d-2")
  params = [:name_first, :name_last, :city]
  updated_params = {}

  CaVoter.transaction do
    cali_voter.each do |cv|
      params.each do |attribute|
        unless cv[attribute] == '' || cv[attribute] == nil
          new_param = cv[attribute].upcase
          updated_params[attribute] = new_param
        end
      end
      cv.update!(updated_params)
      puts updated_params
      file.puts("#{updated_params}\n")
      updated_params = {}
    end
  end
  file.close
end
```

There is no errors but the records are simply not updating

Comment: Why not create a straight SQL UPDATE statement and execute it? SQL handles nulls gracefully and is much faster than iterating through each record. `UPDATE some_table SET first_name = upper(first_name)`

Answer (score 0):

A few comments...

1. Loading 91k objects in active-record is slow and uses lots of memory. You're better off using batches (e.g. `find_each` or `find_in_batches`) to free up the memory as you go. Otherwise this could use a significant amount of memory / take down a server (or do it in SQL).
2. Updating records in a database transaction will acquire exclusive locks on the updated rows. Updating thousands in the same transaction will lock all those rows for the duration of the transaction (which may take a while, especially if done in ruby). If this database is used by other processes/threads, this could cause other threads to be blocked until the transaction commits or aborts, effectively causing an outage.
3. A `update` in a database like postgres is actually implemented as an insert and a delete. Each insert/delete will cause updates to any indexes you have on the table, and bloat your table with dead/deleted rows. If this is updating a large % of the rows in the table and performance becomes an issue, it's significantly more efficient to create a new table with the transformed data, rename the tables and delete the old table than it is to update each row individually. Alternatively you can drop any indexes, do the updates, then re-create the indexes and save a good amount of time. If you don't create a new table you should vacuum your database after an operation like this to remove the dead rows.

So - all in all I'd recommend a SQL-only approach as suggested by dbugger, e.g.

```
task :data_uppercase => [ :environment ] do
  cali_voters = CaVoter.where(tag: "ventura-d-2")
  cali_voters.update_all("name_first = UPPER(name_first), name_last = UPPER(name_last), city = UPPER(city), street_name = UPPER(street_name)")
end
```

Null values will remain null and empty strings will not be impacted.
Updating 91k rows in SQL is likely going to be relatively performant, but it depends on the size of the table, number of indexes, other load, etc. If there is concurrent use of the database it's possible that even this could cause performance issues while the update is executed. You can split this into batches of, say 5-10k if necessary for performance with something like:

```
task :data_uppercase => [ :environment ] do
  cali_voters = CaVoter.where(tag: "ventura-d-2")
  cali_voters.in_batches(of: 5000) do |batch|
    batch.update_all("name_first = UPPER(name_first), name_last = UPPER(name_last), city = UPPER(city), street_name = UPPER(street_name)")
  end
end
```

If you need to write a log of names to the file (as the current code does) and you don't want to run the update in SQL, i'd take an approach like the following:

```
task :data_uppercase => [ :environment ] do
  file = File.open("caVoters.txt", "w")
  cali_voter = CaVoter.where(tag: "ventura-d-2")
  param_names = [:name_first, :name_last, :city, :street_name]

  cali_voter.find_each do |cv|
    attributes_to_upcase = cv.attributes.slice(*param_names).compact
    updated_attributes = attributes_to_upcase.transform_values(&:upcase)
    if updated_attributes != attributes_to_upcase
      cv.update!(updated_attributes)
      file.puts("#{cv.name_first}\n")
    end
  end
  file.close
end
```

The action is idempotent so you don't really need to run in a transaction. If you're worried about needing to re-run in case of failure and don't want to update records a second time unnecessarily you could add a check to the query like `CaVoter.where(tag: "ventura-d-2").where("name_first != UPPER(name_first) OR name_last != UPPER(name_last)")` etc. to skip ones that have already been updated.

Comment: hello @melcher thanks for the extensive reply, i tried the second example you gave but this error prompted NoMethodError: undefined method `update_all' for #<Array:0x000056369a1f6bf8>. any clues?

Comment: Ah, yeah that's my bad - the batch is an array not an activerecord query/proxy. will update the answer

Comment: Updated - the difference is `in_batches` instead of `find_in_batches`. See https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.7/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html for more info/options.